# Activity not launching from a class that has extended Accessibility Service only in android version 12

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, accessibilityservice

I have a class that extends accessibility service and in some certain conditions an activity needs to be launched. In 10,11,13 it works fine and activity launches but in android 12. When logged i get these

```
Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:29189610
```

Code to launch the activity.

```
 private fun launchBlockingActivity(appName: String, appPackage: String?) {
        val context = application.applicationContext
        val blockedIntent = Intent(context, ActivityBlocked::class.java)
        blockedIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
        blockedIntent.putExtra(this.getString(R.string.appName), appName)
        blockedIntent.putExtra(this.getString(R.string.packageName), appPackage)
        context.startActivity(blockedIntent)
    }
```

I tried using ContextCompat to launch but it didn't worked as well, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Information is too scarce...

```
packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()
```

How would you like to try this code?

Comment: would you please tell me how to use this to start the activity?

Comment: val launchIntent = packageManager. getLaunchIntentForPackage("${App Package name}")
startActivity(launchIntent)

Comment: no it didn't work either.